# Better game loop/ engine

Tags: java

I'm fairly new to game programming in Java and I was wondering if someone could help me out with my game loop.  I'm trying to avoid using premade engine libraries (I want to see if I can do it myself).  Currently, my game loop is giving me a really low FPS, sometimes even in the single digits.  Would this be a case where I have to use multithreading? Or is there a better fix to this problem? Any help is much appreciated!

Here is the code which runs the game loop.  I don't include all of the code (because it would be a lot of files), but I think this might be enough, tell me if you need more.  I also include a screenshot of the game that I'm trying to create.  Thanks in advance!

```
package com.Farthorn.game;

import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

public class Game extends Canvas implements Runnable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4431078110090264106L;
    public final static int WIDTH = 640;
    public final static int HEIGHT = WIDTH / 12 * 9;

    private Thread thread;
    private boolean running = false;
    private CharacterHandler cHandler;
    private ObjectHandler oHandler;
    public int change = 0;

    private String mapBackgroundTop = "/Users/Ahhblala/Desktop/FarthornPics/background_top.png";
    private String mapBackgroundBottom = "/Users/Ahhblala/Desktop/FarthornPics/background_bottom.png";
    private Image backgroundTop;
    private Image backgroundBottom;

    public Game()
    {
        ImageIcon i = new ImageIcon(mapBackgroundTop);
        backgroundTop = i.getImage();
        i = new ImageIcon(mapBackgroundBottom);
        backgroundBottom = i.getImage();

        cHandler = new CharacterHandler();
        cHandler.addCharacter(new Player(ID.Player, WIDTH/2-32, HEIGHT/2+64));
        cHandler.addCharacter(new PlantEnemy(ID.PlantEnemy, WIDTH+180, HEIGHT/2+104, (Player)     cHandler.characters.getLast()));
        cHandler.addCharacter(new PlantEnemy(ID.PlantEnemy, WIDTH+195, HEIGHT/2+104, (Player) cHandler.characters.get(0)));
        cHandler.addCharacter(new PlantEnemy(ID.PlantEnemy, WIDTH+300, HEIGHT/2+104, (Player) cHandler.characters.get(0)));
        cHandler.addCharacter(new PlantEnemy(ID.PlantEnemy, WIDTH+315, HEIGHT/2+104, (Player) cHandler.characters.get(0)));

        oHandler = new ObjectHandler();
        oHandler.addObject(new HUD(10, 10, cHandler));

        this.addKeyListener(new KeyInput(cHandler));
        this.addMouseListener(new MouseInput(((Player) cHandler.characters.get(0))));

        FarthornWindow window = new FarthornWindow(WIDTH, HEIGHT, this);


    }

    public synchronized void start()
    {
        running = true;
        thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
    }

    public synchronized void stop()
    {
        try
        {
            thread.join();
            running = false;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void run() 
    {
        this.requestFocus();
        long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
        double amountOfTicks = 60.0;
        double ns = 1000000000 / amountOfTicks;
        double delta = 0;
        long timer = System.currentTimeMillis();
        int frames = 0;
        while (running)
        {
            long now = System.nanoTime();
            delta += (now - lastTime) / ns;
            lastTime = now;
            while (delta >= 1)
            {
                tick();
                delta--;
            }
            if (running)
            {
                render();
            }
            frames++;

            if(System.currentTimeMillis() - timer > 1000)
            {
                timer += 1000;
                System.out.println("FPS " + frames);
                frames = 0;
            }
        }
        stop();
    }

    private void tick()
    {       
        int deltaX = 0;
        int afterX = 0;

        deltaX = cHandler.characters.get(0).getX();

        oHandler.tick();
        cHandler.tick();

        deltaX = cHandler.characters.get(0).getX();
        if (deltaX != afterX)
            change = (afterX-deltaX);
        else
            change = 0;

        render();
    }

    private void render()
    {
        BufferStrategy bs = this.getBufferStrategy();
        if (bs == null)
        {
            this.createBufferStrategy(3);
            return;
        }

        Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();

        g.drawImage(backgroundTop, 0+change, 0, null);
        g.drawImage(backgroundBottom, 0+change, 364, null);

        oHandler.render(g);
        cHandler.render(g);

        g.dispose();
        bs.show();
    }


    public static int clamp(int var, int min, int max)
    {
        if (var >= max)
        {
            return var = max;
        }
        else if (var <= min){
            return var = min;
        }
        else
            return var;
    }

}
```

[image]

As you might be able to tell, I am rendering a lot of outside images.

Comment: You might do better asking this on [codereview.se] but check their help centre before you post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's probably something inefficient in your rendering causing it to drop below your target of 60hz. That aside, there's definitely a problem in your "catch up" loop:

```
    long now = System.nanoTime();
    delta += (now - lastTime) / ns;
    lastTime = now;
    while (delta >= 1)
    {
        tick();
        delta--;
    }
```

Since your tick() routine also calls render(), tick() is effectively a frame in itself, but you are not incrementing your frame counter. Your tick() should be causing all the parts to update, but not render the image, render should only be called once per frame. You probably want to remove the render() line from your tick() routine.

Comment: Wow I didn't even realize I was calling render again, thank you so much that fixed the FPS completely!